# ValueError: time data '2021-04-06T23:51:50.514Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' when converting ISO 8601

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert the time below which i believe is ISO 8601 timestamp but i can't seem to convert.

```
time = '2021-04-06T23:51:50.514Z'

datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: time data '2021-04-06T23:51:50.514Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

Comment: Add a `.%f` between `S` and `Z`. Voting to close this question.

Comment: Your pattern accepts seconds but the value contains milliseconds.

Comment: It may be better to use `dateutil` instead of `strptime`. You'd only need `someDate = parser.parse(time)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you can't parse such a straight forward string with the built-in functions then there's a glaring deficiency in the library.  You shouldn't need an external package for something so simple.

Comment: @MarkRansom said every developer in every language. Java, C#, Python, Javascript. Which is why there are so many external libraries to cover the deficiencies of the languages. `Z` or `+00:00`? IANA timezones or abbreviations? `T` or ` ` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for the general problem of dealing with the multitudes of ways people write dates, I agree - you need a complex library.  But we're talking about an international standard that's tightly specified, it should be possible to handle it with the built-ins.  Particularly in Python which prides itself on [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @MarkRansom but `strptime` can't do it without someone providing the exact format. In C# for example I could use `DateTimeOffset.Parse()` to parse an ISO8601 string without specifying anything more. It would even handle `T` and `Z`, not just the offsets. Unfortunately, it doesn't understand IANA timezone names.

Comment: While you can use simple workarounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418), going with @MarkRansom here, I'd really be interested why the 'Z' for UTC wasn't added to the `fromisoformat` method. Instead, it parses '+00:00' to UTC, which I'd consider kind of wrong; if I'm not mistaken, time zone Europe/London also has zero hours UTC offset if DST is off